# Is WSL 1 / 2 fork() copy-on-write?

Tags: fork, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Originally UNIXes had to copy entire address space for `fork` syscall. Modern UNIXes utilize [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) technique, which avoids costly page copying.

Does WSL 1 / 2 have effective copy on write implementation of `fork()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, WSL 2 supports COW according to a [blog post from Microsoft in 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/wsl/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview):

> *Kyle H 23 April 2016*. How does the fork()/clone() implementation work under the hood? Does it have the lightweight map-all-pages/copy-on-write semantic, or does it have the heavyweight copy-all-pages semantic that original UNIX had?

> *DeepuThomas 26 April 2016*. We will get into more details around our fork implementation in later posts but **yes we do support copy on write**.